# Android: InAppBilling

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, in-app-billing

I am working on an app which has IAB, and that when the purchase is finished through the OnConsumeFinishedListener, it will save through SharePreference that the user has paid for the additional function (the function wont be depleted).

Users are able to buy again for the same product.

## Code:

```
    // Called when consumption is complete
    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() 
    {
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Consumption finished. Purchase: " + purchase + ", result: " + result);
            if (mHelper == null) return;
            if (result.isSuccess()) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(InAppBillingActivity.this, "Thank you!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                if ((purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU10))) {countQ(10);}

        buy10Button.setEnabled(true);

            } 
            else 
            {
                // handle error
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "End consumption flow.");
        }
    };

    public void countQ(int Q) 
    {
        SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("MyApp",0);
        if (Q==10) 
        {

            SharedPreferences settings1 = this.getSharedPreferences("MyApp",0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor e1 = settings1.edit();
            e1.putBoolean("userpaid", true);
            e1.commit();                        
        }
```

## Question:

I see that users are able to cancel their purchase. In that way, saving through Sharepreference that the user has paid for additional functions will have loophole? The user can first purchase to make the sharepreference to become `true` and then cancel the purchase order?

In that way, how can be the process be improved? Checking the inventory seem not possible as the additional function is `consumed` in the IAB process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a little odd that you have a non-consumable item that can be purchased multiple times. The idea is generally that an item that can be purchased multiple times is consumable.

To answer your question IAB purchases cannot be cancelled like an app purchase can, the 15 minute refund window is removed and the purchase is non-refundable unless they contact you and you decide to issue a refund manually.

Comment: thanks so much for your prompt responses! The "purchase" is actually a kind of donation + additional functionality, which let users to donate more than once if they wish, and if he has donated, the sharedpreference will become true. In your reply, that means IAB is unlike paying paid app, orders in IAB CANNOT be cancelled and therefore in this regards, no loophole for saving the flag in this way? I am curious and keep thinking whether there will be any case where user has not paid yet the flag become true. Do you have some advice?

Comment: Unless there is a bug elsewhere in your code a user can't simulate a purchase without actually purchasing it. Once purchased it is permanent and cannot be refunded unless you choose to refund it. Hope that helps.